# my current/total of downloads are not showing on google developer account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-play, accountmanager

I have created my account two days ago but total download is not showing, but the number of people that rated the app is both showing on google play and the developer account

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about customer support from a vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/developer-console.html). You can see it under all applications or go into the respective app and into the **Statistics** tab. I believe it can take up to a day for statistics to update.